# How to fix "gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available" when running "lein deploy clojars"?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, gnupg

I've been trying for ages to deploy a library to clojars without having to specify username and password using `lein deploy clojars`. But I end up with the following error message:

```
gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session
gpg: can't query passphrase in batch mode
gpg: Invalid passphrase; please try again ...
gpg: can't query passphrase in batch mode
gpg: Invalid passphrase; please try again ...
gpg: can't query passphrase in batch mode
gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available
Could not decrypt credentials from /Users/johan/.lein/credentials.clj.gpg
nil
See `lein help gpg` for how to install gpg.
No credentials found for clojars
See `lein help deploying` for how to configure credentials to avoid prompts.
```

My `~./lein/credentials.clj.gpg` looks like this (unencrypted):

```
{ #"https://clojars.org/repo"
 {:username "<username>" :password "<password>"}}}
```

I know that the username and password are correct (they are just copied from 1password).

Running `gpg --list-keys` gives me:

```
/Users/myname/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
-------------------------------
pub   2048R/0486A2C5 2010-10-12
uid                  My Name <myname@somemail.com>
sub   2048R/0617110A 2010-10-12
```

I've tried specifiying both `0486A2C5` and `0617110A` in `~/.lein/profiles.clj` (`:signing {:gpg-key "<key>"}`) but it doesn't make any difference.

I've also made sure that `use-agent` is uncommented in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` and I've also made sure that `gpg-agent` is installed on my machine (`brew install gpg-agent`).

**Update 1**

Running `gpg --list-secret-keys` gives me:

```
/Users/myname/.gnupg/secring.gpg
-------------------------------
sec   2048R/0486A2C5 2010-10-12
uid                  My Name <myname@somemail.com>
ssb   2048R/0617110A 2010-10-12
```

Running `gpg --quiet --batch --decrypt ~/.lein/credentials.clj.gpg` prompts me for my password and then yields the unencrypted results.

**Update 2**

I'm using gpg 1.4.20 and gpg-agent 2.0.29 (both installed using brew) on Mac OS X El Capitan.

What am I missing!?

Comment: Can you provide the full command line with which GnuPG is called? Might GnuPG be ran in another user's context? `gpg --list-keys` prints public keys, decryption needs the secret key. What is the outptu of `gpg --list-secret-keys`?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: It cannot prompt for a password when being run by lein, that's why the agent is needed. Is it prompting via the same TTY or via GUI popup?

Comment: Some ascii ui in the terminal so I suppose tty

Comment: Ok so it seems to work if I first do "gpg --quiet --batch --decrypt ~/.lein/credentials.clj.gpg" and THEN run "lein deploy clojars". But if I wait too long between the commands it won't work. Why is this!?

Comment: Before these two commands I also need to run "eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)"

Comment: But the signing process still doesn't work. Here it says "gpg: problem with the agent - disabling agent use"

Comment: I think the source of this problem is that the agent from homebrew wants to use stdin (it is not a gui app right?) and lein can't give it stdin, so it fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by uninstalling gpg from brew (`brew uninstall gpg`) and then install the binaries from [gpgtools](https://gpgtools.org/installer/index.html). I then opened the terminal and created a symbolic link from gpg2 to gpg:

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin/gpg2 /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin/gpg
```

Then I added `/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin` to the `PATH` in my `~/.profile`. When running `lein clojars deploy` I now get a graphical user interface where I enter the password and afterwards it successfully signs the release and publish the artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to address this issue is to attempt to decrypt a file using gpg with the `--batch` flag. I think you'll find that your agent is installed but has not been started, or is perhaps improperly configured. If you can get gpg to work with --batch, then the deploy command will work.

Comment: It works when I do "gpg --use-agent --quiet --batch --decrypt ~/.lein/credentials.clj.gpg" but then when it's about to sign the artifacts (when I run "lein deploy clojars") it says "gpg: problem with the agent - disabling agent use" and fails

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that naming the jar file you want to deploy with `-SNAPSHOT` on the end means that you do not have to set up public/private keys.

Comment: True, and that works for me too, but I want to deploy a non snapshot version.